# Add multiple popups on a leaflet map without overlapping

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a marker cluster, and for some reason our customer would like to click on the cluster and have all the popups open for that cluster at a specific zoom level. I have completed the opening of the popups based on the cluster click, however, how do I choose the setLatLng for the popups so they do not overlap? I would like to create a circle with the popups, but not exactly sure how to figure out the coordinates???